# Plot Change in Total Production Across Different Continents Over the Years

Tags: r, ggplot2, visualization, data-analysis

This is the sample of data:

```
continent   long    lat group   order   region  subregion   Year_Range  Total_Production
<chr>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <int>   <chr>   <chr>   <chr>   <dbl>
Americas    -67.7268066 44.566502   1501    92481   USA NA  1980-1990   1055237
Asia    47.3313446  30.079689   848 53242   Iraq    NA  2000-2010   521445404
Africa  -13.4869633 16.097021   1026    64641   Mauritania  NA  1970-1980   158107
Oceania 149.9418945 -22.308105  177 8035    Australia   NA  1960-1970   85200
Asia    97.9084015  4.879981    823 50337   Indonesia   Sumatra 1990-2000   262865493
Asia    129.8283234 32.892673   881 55035   Japan   Kyushu  Until 2018  805169237
Europe  -6.2612791  57.009521   579 40290   UK  Scotland    Until 2018  24689482
```

I am trying to plot the change in production across different continents over the years however I am not able to pull out the solution.

Here is my code:

```
ggplot(merge_data, aes(x = long, y = lat, fill = continent,size = Total_Production)) +
geom_point() +
scale_color_manual(values = c("Americas" = "blue", 
                              "Asia" = "red", 
                              "Africa" = "green",
                              "Oceania" = "purple", 
                              "Europe" = "orange")) +
labs(title = "Total_Production By Continent",
     subtitle = "Year Range: 1960 - 2018") +
theme_minimal()
```

Need your kind support to solve this issue. Thank you.

I want to make a proper visualization for the change in total production across different continents over the years.

Answer (score 0):

Does this work in your aes you have used fill = continent change this to color = continent and it should work, geop_point goes with color aesthetic not fill

```
merge_data = data.frame(
         continent = c("Americas","Asia","Africa",
                       "Oceania","Asia","Asia","Europe"),
              long = c(-67.7268066,47.3313446,
                       -13.4869633,149.9418945,97.9084015,129.8283234,-6.2612791),
               lat = c(44.566502,30.079689,16.097021,
                       -22.308105,4.879981,32.892673,57.009521),
             group = c(1501L, 848L, 1026L, 177L, 823L, 881L, 579L),
             order = c(92481L, 53242L, 64641L, 8035L, 50337L, 55035L, 40290L),
            region = c("USA","Iraq","Mauritania",
                       "Australia","Indonesia","Japan","UK"),
         subregion = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, "Sumatra", "Kyushu", "Scotland"),
        Year_Range = c("1980-1990","2000-2010",
                       "1970-1980","1960-1970","1990-2000","Until -2018",
                       "Until - 2018"),
  Total_Production = c(1055237L,521445404L,158107L,
                       85200L,262865493L,805169237L,24689482L)
)
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(merge_data, aes(x = long, y = lat, color = continent,size = Total_Production)) +
    geom_point() +
    scale_color_manual(values = c("Americas" = "blue", 
                                  "Asia" = "red", 
                                  "Africa" = "green",
                                  "Oceania" = "purple", 
                                  "Europe" = "orange")) +
    labs(title = "Total_Production By Continent",
         subtitle = "Year Range: 1960 - 2018") +
    theme_minimal()
```